# how to ignore Wdefaulted-function-deleted clang warning?

Tags: c++, clang

I'm working on project to upgrade it's toolchain which will upgrade the compiler from clang-8 to clang-14. In that case i got a lot of new errors generated for examples this one -Wdefaulted-function-deleted so my questions are :

```
1- how to find the history of such error(basically it's a warning) it means on which clang release it was added ?
2- How could I ignore this kind of warning or how to not treat them as errors ?
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You probably pass `-Werror` to treat warning as error...

Comment: The proper action would probably be to just take a deep breath and remove all the functions where you get this warning. Other warnings may need other actions, but for this particular warning, just do it.

Comment: But i was using old toolchain from google using clang-8 it didn't raise such error, so this change is made on their toolchain

Comment: The change to inform you about the deleted function is made in clang, yes. I suspect it still removed the function in the older clang version though. What happens if you just remove one of the defaulted functions that it complains about? Was the function actually used anywhere in your code? Add `-Wno-defaulted-function-deleted` and see if it compiles without the offending function

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks for your answer. I am stuck on finding a documentation on how to suppress these warnings, for example I tried the same way for "Wimplicit-int-conversion" warning by addin the "Wno-" prefix but it didn't work. is there an other way to ignore this warning or other syntax ?

Comment: Are you saying you got the `defaulted-function-deleted` warning even if you added `-Wno-defaulted-function-deleted`? That sounds odd - unless your code actually uses deleted functions that the old compiler forgot to remove. If that's the case, you need to correct your code.

Comment: @TedLyngmo no for "-Wno-defaulted-function-deleted" it's working but i tried to do the same logic with this warning "Wimplicit-int-conversion" with trying via ""Wno-implicit-int-conversion" but it didn't work and i didn't find documentation on how to ignore this last warning that's why i asked you to suggest me what to do.

Comment: I find it easiest and best to just fix those issues. Usually when I do go though a thousand of them to fix them, I also find and fix a couple of real bugs.